# Evaluating math proofs by computer

Tags: computer-science

Is there any way to evaluate (check) math proofs (entered in some convenient for computer form) by computer?
Only thing that comes to my mind is functional programming, different logics, but I'm not sure if it has any relation.

Comment: [Automated proof checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_proof_checking) is a thing, but I'd assume that the input to any such program would be very different from what you'd ordinarily write as a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/). It is an advanced formal proof system.